# Newest chrome changes tailwind styles behaviour

Tags: google-chrome, tailwind-css, angular17

I noticed a weird behavior in my application and hope for some debugging tips because I am lost.
I update from Angular 17.0.6 to Angular 17.1. I have a standard tailwind configuration and I use nx.
When I update Chrome (well, my coworker confirmed this), the background color settings won't work anymore even if everything is rebuild from scratch.
Tested with the most simple div

```
<div class="w-full h-full bg-green-500">test</div>
```

the width and height settings are properly applied, only the background settings dont work (also, relative and absolute positioning seem to be off but I can't fully say for sure that it is due to the update)

Any help, confirmations of the issue,.... greatly appreaciated. I am willing to provide information, but I don't know what might be of interest

Comment: What do you see when you inspect the element? Does the `bg-green-500` apply _any_ styling? Does Chrome show anything crossed-out because it was overwritten by a rule with more specific selector? Does it show the warning triangle for any invalid rule or property?

Comment: The weirdest thing happend:
I tried to answer your question but could not find any crossed out things or the like. Not sure why (i saw some inheritet values), so I decied to wrap my bg div in another div. This lead to a background as expected. When removing the div to provide a more useful answer, I could not reproduce the problem anymore. Happy it is "solved" but still weirded out

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth:
The problem seemed to be browser specific. I wrapped my div in another div (without styling or anything) and rerendered my page. Then I removed said wrapper div and the styling worked as expected.